# How to use syntax code highlighting using next-mdx-remote?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, markdown

I'm trying to highlight my code syntax using `next-mdx-remote` in my Nextjs based page. I'm getting my markdown format from `graphcms` and rendering it like this :

```
import { serialize } from "next-mdx-remote/serialize"
import { MDXRemote } from "next-mdx-remote"
import rehypeHighlight from "rehype-highlight"


export async function getStaticProps({ params }: any) {
  const data = await getPostDetail(params?.slug)

  const source = data?.content?.markdown
  const mdxSource = await serialize(source, {
    mdxOptions: { rehypePlugins: [rehypeHighlight] },
  })

  return {
    props: {
      posts: data,
      mdxSource: mdxSource,
    },
  }
}


function Post({mdxSource}){
  return(
    <MDXRemote {...mdxSource} />
  )
}
```

Unfortunately, the code blocks gets rendered like normal text fields and doesn't do anything.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, the official [documentation](https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-remote) doesn't clarify this as well

Comment: rehype-highlight is huge, It is 942k. I'm using this in my NextJS project and it is causing performance issues. Does anyone know any solution?

Comment: if you're doing this in Next.js 13 then it'll default to server-side rendering meaning none of that package size will be sent to the client. Instead it is pre-rendered into html before the client receives it

Answer (score 4):

According to [mdx docs](https://mdxjs.com/guides/syntax-highlighting/#syntax-highlighting-at-compile-time) you want to include the below link somewhere in your header.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.4.0/styles/github-dark.min.css"></link>
```

let me know if it doesn't work. it works for me at the least.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add some css? For example

`import "highlight.js/styles/atom-one-dark.css";`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the highlight style in your header

```js
import { serialize } from "next-mdx-remote/serialize"
import { MDXRemote } from "next-mdx-remote"
import rehypeHighlight from "rehype-highlight"


export async function getStaticProps({ params }: any) {
  const data = await getPostDetail(params?.slug)

  const source = data?.content?.markdown
  const mdxSource = await serialize(source, {
    mdxOptions: { rehypePlugins: [rehypeHighlight] },
  })

  return {
    props: {
      posts: data,
      mdxSource: mdxSource,
    },
  }
}


function Post({mdxSource}){
  return(
    <>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/water.css@2/out/dark.css"></link>
    <MDXRemote {...mdxSource} />
    </>
  )
}
```

And to enhance your code you can add this style inside the `Head` element or inside the document file which allows you to inject extra components styles, SEO,... etc.
`_document.js`

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/dracula-prism/dist/css/dracula-prism.css"
          ></link>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Answer (score 0):

`rehype-highlight` on its own only adds css classnames to your html code blocks. You then need to import a highlight.js stylesheet to style these blocks.

You can download them from [here](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/tree/main/src/styles) and then import them into your page like this:

```
import "@/styles/highlight-js/github-dark.css"
```

A full tutorial can be found here: https://gaudion.dev/blog/mdx-syntax-highlighting